# Input multiple field data through a form in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

Thanks to all in advance for their help and input.

I have a growing business where I work with small university sports teams in lining up hotel accommodations when they play at other universities.  Using Access 2010, I have one data table for hotels and a corresponding form where I can input and update hotel information.  Then I have another data table where I track proximity to universities by hotel.  So, for example, if I have a team playing in St. Louis, I might have one hotel with close proximity to UM St. Louis, Missouri Baptist, and Washington University.

My goal is to be able to input multiple universities and their corresponding distance from hotel on my hotel input form and obviously have my proximity table updated with the input.  I've created the relationship in the form to link the two tables together, created multiple combo boxes with the intent of inputting more than one can only input one university at present.

Can someone suggest a methodology for achieving this?  Thank you once again for the assistance.

Comment: Please post the code/schemas you have created already.

Comment: Which table(s) do(es) the university get stored?

Comment: @MattHall - Destination venues / universities are stored in an independent table - Destination Venues.

Comment: @mjuarez - 

Not sure exactly how to portray this, esp in under 600 characters.  My three main tables for this exercise are Hotel, Hotel Dist to Venue and Destination Venue.  If I could screen shot a few things I would to show relationships.  What tools in Access should I be looking at to achieve this?